# How do I add text stroke to pango for moviepy?

Tags: python, moviepy, pango

I am able to add colors, italics, and bold to change text in my `srt` for `moviepy` which is great, but `pango` does not have a stroke property how could I implement this?

After searching for a few hours I could not find a solution anywhere. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask